# Requests Not Creating Images Python

Tags: python, python-requests

I want to download images. But for some reason the code execute without errors but it's not creating any images.
I'm using `Requests` and `BeautifulSoup`. My IDE is VS Code

```
HEADERS = {'User-Agent': "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.135 Safari/537.36 Edge/12.246"}
def getData(link):
  URL = link
  request = requests.get(url=URL, headers=HEADERS)
  result = BeautifulSoup(request.content, "lxml")
  return result
address = "https://bisesargodha.edu.pk/content/ViewSeqImges.aspx?SubjectId=760&SeqNameAnsSubj=Sequence1"
response = getData(address)
table = response.find('table', attrs = {'id':'ContentPlaceHolder1_Table1'})
imgs = table.findAll('img')
imgNum = 1
for img in imgs:
    image_url = f"https://bisesargodha.edu.pk/content/{img['src']}"
    image_save = f"img-{imgNum}.jpg"
    pull_image = requests.get(image_url, headers=HEADERS)
    pull_image_contant = pull_image.content
    with open(image_save, "wb+") as myfile:
        myfile.write(pull_image_contant)
    imgNum = imgNum + 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to fetch and consume your response as a stream, try something like this:

```py
img_num = 1
for img in imgs:
    image_url = f"https://bisesargodha.edu.pk/content/{img['src']}"
    image_save = f"img-{img_num}.jpg"

    with requests.get(image_url, headers=HEADERS, stream=True) as resp:
        resp.raise_for_status() # do some additional error handling if necessary
        with open(image_save, "wb") as image_file:
            for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=8192): 
                image_file.write(chunk)

    img_num = img_num + 1
```

If the issue still persists then maybe double check the image urls you are constructing and make sure they are really pointing to the right content.